# Get Average in SQL Through Join

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, subquery

I'm just playing around with SQL and I'm trying to do the following.

I have 2 tables and here is their structure:

1. Movies_metadata [Movies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySsVq.png)
2. ratings table:
   [Ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dThuB.png)

As there are many ratings for one movie, what I'd like to do is get the avg rating per movie and have it display next to the title which is only available in the Metadata table.

This is as far as I got but obviously the issue with my SELECT statement is that it'll return the average of all movies and display it for each record:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
        AVG(rating)
    FROM 
        `movies-dataset.movies_data.ratings`) AS rating_avg,
    metadata.title,
    metadata.budget,
    metadata.revenue,
    metadata.genres,
    metadata.original_language,
    metadata.release_date
FROM 
    `movies-dataset.movies_data.Movies_metadata` AS metadata
INNER JOIN `movies-dataset.movies_data.ratings` AS ratings
    ON metadata.id = ratings.movieId
LIMIT 10
```

Here is an example of the result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpM4F.png)

I'm thinking I can potentially use a GROUP BY but when I try, I get an error

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk? And post the actual table definitions in the post, instead of linking to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT movies_metadata.title, AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM movies_metadata
LEFT JOIN ratings ON movies_metadata.id = ratings.movieID
GROUP BY movies_metadata.title
```

You can swap `movies_metadata.title` by `movies_metadata.id` if not unique.

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT function and GROUP function might conflict with each other. Try getting the average rating as part of the inner join like this:

```
    SELECT
    ratings.averagerating,
    metadata.title,
    metadata.budget,
    metadata.revenue,
    metadata.genres,
    metadata.original_language,
    metadata.release_date
FROM `movies-dataset.movies_data.Movies_metadata` AS metadata
INNER JOIN (SELECT movieId, AVG(rating) averagerating FROM `movies-dataset.movies_data.ratings` GROUP by movieId) AS ratings
    ON metadata.id = ratings.movieId
ORDER BY ratings.averagerating
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
Select m.movieID, (r.rate_sum / r.num_rate) as avg_rating
From your_movies_table m
Left Join (select movie_id, sum(rating) as ‘rate_sum’, count(rating) as ‘num_rate’
From your_ratings_table
Group by movie_id) r
On m.movie_id = r.movie_id
```

I'm using a left join because I'm not sure if all movies have been rated at least once.